# Passing parameter in a class of c++ file to a thread in header file

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am currently working on a program which have a main cpp linked to a header file. There is a thread called in main cpp but the thread was defined in the header file.

Now I noticed that the main cpp file can use the parameters which defined in thread without define.But when I try to use a parameter which defined in a class of main cpp file in the thread, it gives error not declared in this scope.

I am bit new to cpp, any guidance how should I pass the parameter in a class of main cpp file to a thread in header file?

Comment: Headers for class declarations, .cpp source files for scoped definitions. Beyond that we can't help without you being more specific and showing some code. Also, I'm not sure if you really mean "thread".

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you mean and want?